# Sass mixin animations not applied properly

Tags: html, css, sass

I am trying to create a hamburger menu with close animation using **SCSS**. But for some reason, the animations not work as expected.

Both red bars rotate in the same direction, although i have given them opposite directions in the mixins.

```
@mixin bar-rotation($deg){
    @keyframes bar-rotation {
        0% {
            transform: rotate(0);
        }
        100% {
            transform: rotate($deg);
        }
    }

    animation-name: bar-rotation;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-duration: 0.2s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.bar-first-transformed {
    @extend .bar-first;
    @include bar-rotation(45deg);
}

.bar-third-transformed {
    @extend .bar-third;
    @include bar-rotation(-45deg);
}
```

**Full code in JS Fiddle:**
https://jsfiddle.net/ntfzy2g5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no notions of scope for animations functions in SCSS. In other words, if you use the same animation name twice, you transform the animation, which remains the same for all elements that call it up.
You can either find a way to give a unique name to your animation, like with a random generated string, or use `transition` and classes to animate from `0deg` to `$deg`. I would highly recommend the last over generating multiple animations.

```scss
%bar {
    // ...
    transition: .2s linear;
}
@mixin bar-rotation($deg) {
    transform: rotate($deg);
}
// ...
.bar-first-transformed {
    @extend .bar-first;
    .navigation-menu-button.active & {
       @include bar-rotation(45deg);      
    }
}
// OR
.navigation-menu-button {
    // ...
    &.active {
        .bar-first {
            @include bar-rotation(45deg);
        } // and so on
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank your very much for the idea! I have inserted the parameter into the animation name, and it works now.